# Выводится значение только первого чекбокса

Tags: php, sql, json, ооп, mvc

имеется список с чекбоксами, у каждого чекбокса имеется значение (соответствует id раздела), при нажатии на кнопку передаются POST данные (значение нажатой кнопки и значение чекбокса) проблема в том что, передается значение только первого чекбокса, все остальных НЕТ, но если смотреть исходный код, то там все значения на месте, что может быть не так?

```
  <div class="main">
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="h2">info</h2>
  <a href="index" ><img src="/public/styles/img/back.png" width="25" height="25" alt="back" style="position:absolute;margin-top:-25px; margin-left: 70px;"></a>
  <form action="/miners/miner" method="POST">
      <div class="button">
        <input type="submit" class="but btn-reset" name="submit" id="sub" value="start">
        <input type="submit" class="but btn-reset" name="submit" id="sub" value="stop">
        <input type="submit" class="but btn-reset" name="submit" id="sub" value="restart">
        <input type="submit" class="but btn-reset" name="submit" id="sub" value="reboot">
        <input type="submit" class="but btn-reset" name="submit" id="sub" value="add/change">
        <input type="submit" class="but btn-reset" name="submit" id="sub" value="filter">
      </div>

  <div class="title">
    <span class="descr">Description</span>
    <span class="descr">Status</span>
    <span class="descr">Progress</span>
    <span class="descr">Perfomanse</span>
    <span class="descr">Info</span>
  </div>

<?php foreach ($data as $val): ?>
  <div class="info">
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="<? echo $val['id']; ?>">
    <div class="func"><a href="/info/test/<? echo $val['owner']; ?>">
 <? echo $val['name'] ?></a></div>
</div>
</form>

 <?php endforeach; ?>

 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

**Контроллер**

```
 public function infoAction() {
    if(!empty($_POST)) {
        $this->model->start($_POST);

        $this->view->message('seccess', 'ok'); // Сообщение о удачи

    } 
    $result = $this->model->select(); // Вывод данных
    $vars = [
        'data' => $result,
    ];
    
    $this->view->render('test', $vars); 
}
```

**Модель**

```
public function start($post) {
    $params = [
        'command' => $post['submit'],
        'submit' => $post['id'],


    ];
    debug($_POST);
    $this->db->query('UPDATE sections SET command = :command WHERE id = :submit', $params);
    
}
```

Comment: @Alex Khonko, ниже смотрите , чекбокс идёт в цикле foreach

Comment: виноват. У вас name должен быть в виде массива. Попробуйте вместо `name="id"` сделать `name="id[]"`

Comment: @Alex Khonko, Пробовал, не помогает( так же значение первого чекбокса записывается ив сё

Comment: name поставьте разный

Comment: @Alex khonko, не получится, чек бокс же выводится   циклом, одна строка <input type="checkbox"....